# How to handle Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, error-handling, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to error handling and I need help with this error
Short Q = What to do please explain it with simple answer

```
<Error> 
<Code>AccessDenied</Code> 
<Message>Access denied.</Message> 
<Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details> 
</Error>
```

Help really appreciated

Comment: Can you provide more context? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to download unity editor but it failed so im checking the domain that I tried to whitelist and theres a error (upm-cdn.unity.com)@guillaume blaquiere

Comment: Can you share the URL that you use to download? I will have a try

Comment: well the download is on the unity hub itself soo

Comment: I have no issue to download on my side. Can you share the link that you use?

Comment: Well I want to download Unity Editor from Hub. It says instalation failed so I contacted support, he says I need to whitelist 3 package link maybe on firewall (check unity network issue) I checked 3 link from that website and 1 of them (link on my first comment) causes error Anonymus caller does not have (on Question) so ye I dont think its about download

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you didn't contain authorization header in your request.

To access to GCS bucket, You have to authorize your account via OAuth 2.0 access token.

Refer [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) to get information about how to authenticate your api call.

Of course, Your account used for authenticate must have appropriate IAM role to get bucket object.

Check your account's IAM role in IAM page.

[image]